# How do I increase Steam UI font size on Steam Deck in Desktop Mode?

Tags: steam, steam-deck

When I open Steam on my Steam Deck in Desktop mode the font is tiny and most of the things are completely unreadable. This is how my Steam fonts looks like in comparison with my browser fonts:
[image]

How do I make it bigger?

I've tried "GDK_SCALE" solution from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1341302/893990) , but it doesn't seem to work. I modified `steam-jupiter` file (I run `sudo steamos-readonly disable` and `chmod` some permissions before):

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin/steam
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Nov 22 15:56 /usr/bin/steam -> /usr/bin/steam-jupiter

$ ls -la /usr/bin/steam-jupiter
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1234 Nov 22 15:56 /usr/bin/steam-jupiter

$ sudo vim /usr/bin/steam-jupiter
```